# dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc (on Mac)

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, dyld

I did a regular `flutter run` on my Mac, targeting my iPhone simulator today and got these errors.

```sh
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc
      Referenced from: /Users/toure/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
      Expected in: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib

    dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc
      Referenced from: /Users/toure/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
      Expected in: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
```

How do you solve the `dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc` error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a fix buried in a [github issue](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/687#issuecomment-468005152).

Running this on my Mac solved the problem.

```sh
gem uninstall ffi
brew reinstall libffi
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
gem install ffi
```

I decided to share this since the error in the title of the issue is different from the one that I got. Hope this can save someone some time.

Comment: Wow! After trying a lot of things: reinstall FFI, Ruby… nothing fixed the issue. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks! 

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve this by reinstalling the utility with this flag:

`gem install ffi -- --disable-system-libffi`

Turns out `ffi-1.13.1` is using `ffi_prep_closure_loc()` and `system-libffi` for Mac doesn’t have that function.

See `ffi` issue #[791](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/791) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Toure's solution, but for newer Homebrew installs:

```sh
gem uninstall ffi
brew reinstall libffi
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
gem install ffi
```

Answer (score 0):

for M1 v13 Ventura, you should be able to install older version with:

`gem install ffi -v '1.11.1' -- --enable-libffi-alloc`
ref. https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/800#issuecomment-748434595

but problem was when running after `rake db:create` got again same error.
So only what did help, like mentioned in reference:

```
gem install ffi -v '1.14.0'
And changing also to this version in gemfile.lock
```